# active record association isn't loading unless "included" from the original look-up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, associations, belongs-to

Why does the client_destination association return nil unless it was "included" from the original model look-up!?

```
class Placement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client_destination_type

  belongs_to :client_destination,
    :polymorphic => true,
    :foreign_type => 'client_destination_type_class_name'

  def client_destination_type_class_name
    client_destination_type.class_name
  end
end
```

Without include (broken):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :021 > Placement.last.client_destination
  Placement Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `placements`.* FROM `placements` WHERE (placements.deleted_at IS NULL) ORDER BY `placements`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

With include (works):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :022 > Placement.last(:include => :client_destination).client_destination
  Placement Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `placements`.* FROM `placements` WHERE (placements.deleted_at IS NULL) ORDER BY `placements`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  ClientDestinationType Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `client_destination_types`.* FROM `client_destination_types` WHERE `client_destination_types`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  ClientSite Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `client_sites`.* FROM `client_sites` WHERE `client_sites`.`id` IN (3000018)
 => #<ClientSite id: 3000018, name: "WTF.com", created_at: "2011-08-09 12:23:51", updated_at: "2011-08-09 12:23:51", user_group_id: 23510, client_ad_tag_code_id: nil>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from what you've got posted, but I would guess it's the dynamic foreign_type selector you've got misbehaving with the default loading.

I would guess an order of operations thing with the client_destination_type association being loaded to generate the value for client_destination_type_class_name() method used in the other association.

You could confirm or deny this by swapping out:

```
belongs_to :client_destination,
  :polymorphic => true,
  :foreign_type => 'ClientSite'
```

and seeing if the association lazy-loads correctly for that static type.

Comment: that doesn't work because foreign_type is supposed to be the column name that holds the value, not the value itself. that's why the method works (in one case at least). what i really need is to join the client_destination_type table in the association but haven't yet figured out how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

this fixed it (default scope):

```
class Placement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client_destination_type

  default_scope :joins => :client_destination_type

  belongs_to :client_destination,
    :polymorphic => true,
    :foreign_type => 'client_destination_types.class_name'
end
```

Comment: false alarm. that seemed to work for a while but then stopped.

Comment: ah, another gem is wiping the default scope; so in theory this works.